# Can javascript embedded in a C++ program faster than javascript on the web

Tags: javascript, c++, performance, v8, spidermonkey

I'm strictly a beginner with C++, but I was wondering if javascript (or Lua or any scripting language) running inside a C++ program is subject to the same kind of hardware acceleration that the C++ code can offer.

I realize this would require having a js engine somewhere in your program, but was curious if this javascript would be inherently faster/better for whatever reason.

Comment: Javascript will still be javascript. Most if not all modern interpreters are already running from C or C++ based code.

Answer (score 3):

As you said, such a program would have to use some sort of javascript engine, highly likely one that is already used in browsers like V8. Any speed gains (if any) would mainly come from application design. Your program probably doesn't have to use as many resources and abstractions intertwined with the javascript.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript itself is an interpreted/translated language. It is possible to write your own interpreter or translator for it (and if you are really clever, do it better than the existing ones...), but it's a large task to do something that "works", never mind improve on the existing ones, and most likely it would be hard to cover all the quirks and "it works this way in Firefox, and that way in IE7, some different way in IE8+" type workarounds that websites use.

If you use a pre-existing JS interpreter, there is little or no benefit.

Comment: V8 compiles javascript to IA-32, x86/64 and ARM machine code; Javascript is no more an interpreted language than C.

Comment: To elaborate: Translation method (eg. "interpretation vs. compilation") is a decision made by the implementation of the language (eg. the translator, be it a compiler or an interpreter), not by the language itself.

Comment: It's more of a "just in time" compilation tho', and it has features that can't be resolved (such as "eval") that can't be dealt with in any other way than direct interpretation.

Comment: Also, in my experience, if you have an error in a function, it is often only detected when it's called.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue, just because V8 has a nice JIT hardly justifies the idea that we shouldn't call Javascript an "interpreted language" in general.

Comment: "Just in time" refers to optimisation, not compilation or interpretation. "Interpreters" translate source code directly to behaviour. "Compilers" translate source code to another programming language. V8 is definitely a compiler. The `eval` feature can be resolved the same way an interpreter resolves it: By linking `eval` back to the translation mechanism. This has nothing to do with "interpreted" vs "compiled".

Comment: @CharlesSalvia Ten years ago, people would have been telling you that "Java is an interpreted language, in general"... Nowadays, nobody denies that the most common Java implementation compiles source code to a bytecode format (see the definitions of "interpreter" and "compiler" above). SO is forever!

Comment: @modifiablelvalue, whether we call a language "interpreted" or "compiled" is admittedly somewhat subjective, but Java has a pre-runtime compilation phase, whereas Javascript is almost always "interpreted" on the fly in common usage, albeit with many modern optimizations such as JIT compilation.

Comment: @CharlesSalvia Consider the invalidity of *"Javascript is almost always "interpreted" on the fly in the common usage" when using V8 to compile javascript source code*. I've already responded to "JIT compilation" nonsense. JIT is an optimisation technique, just like AOT. These aren't exclusive of either interpretation or compilation. Thus, JIT and AOT is irrelevant (though compiling to native machine code *is considered* an AOT optimisation). I'm over and out...

Answer (score 0):

Speed is not an attribute introduced by language, but by implementation. One Javascript translator might be written using algorithms considered to be optimal, while another might be written using sloppy, slow algorithms. The algorithms used in the Javascript source code would be the most significant attempts at optimisation.

Similarly, a C++ compiler will often try to automatically optimise the code. An implementation of C++ might produce an Javascript translator considered to be optimal for one machine but extremely slow for another, while another might produce a Javascript translator perfectly optimal or slow for both machines.